# Execute Spring Job every hour

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to configure Spring job to be executed every hour. I tried this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * *")
```

But the job is executed every several times for one minute. What is the proper configuration?

Answer (score 1):

`0 0 * * * *`: at 0 seconds and 0 minutes, every hour, every day, every month, every day of week.

Answer (score 0):

Cron scheduling can be confusing;
Instead of trying to hack this out.

Check out this https://crontab.guru/